# Obscuring a bottom part of the screen by a "curtain" while displaying a pdf file

Tags: pdf

Is there a way to obscure a bottom part of the screen by a "curtain" while displaying a pdf file? I would like to be able to do that while using a classroom lcd projector, so that I can make students focus on the upper part of a page and ask questions before showing the rest of the page. The curtain should be easily movable up and down, like a blank page covering part of display in the old style overhead projectors.

Obviously, the "curtain" program could be independent of pdf viewer, as long as it can work with a pdf viewer in the full screen mode.

(Anticipating comments: slide shows with layers eliminate need for a curtain, but 1. preparing them takes a lot more time and time if of the essence 2. I need to display certain pdf documents which are not slide shows.)

Comment: Why did you tag this jQuery/CSS? Are you using a web browser in full screen mode to display the PDF file? Isn't zooming in enough to hide the bottom part of a page?

Comment: Drag a window from another program on top of the bottom half. Under Windows, a window can be set to stay "always on top" -- a very obnoxious thing to do but in this case it's actually *useful* for a change.